# Extract diagonals from a rectangle given as a list of sequences (Python)

Tags: python, string, list

I need help with change order of list of strings.
For example:

```
Matrix_List = ['bnnp', 'yior', 'ente', 'femf']
b n n p
y i o r
e n t e
f e m f
```

and I want to change it to this(like build a new list according to that direction ↘ :

```
b i t f
y n m
e e
f
n o e
n r 
p
Matrix_list = ['bitf', 'ynm','ee','f','noe','nr','p']
```

Any help whould be appreciate.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I dont ask for code, I ask for guidance

Comment: Write some code to do the work, maybe recursive, maybe in a for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform your grid like so

```
       b n n p
     y i o r
   e n t e
 f e m f
```

and then retrieve the columns using `zip`:

```
Matrix_List = ['bnnp', 'yior', 'ente', 'femf']
n = len(Matrix_List)
pad = (n-1) * ['']
padded = [pad[i:] + list(word) + pad[:i] for i, word in enumerate(Matrix_List)]
result = [''.join(column) for column in zip(*padded)]
```

Comment: and I want this position : ↙ ? how do I do it?

Comment: Can you explain this line :" padded = [pad[i:] + list(word) + pad[:i] for i, word in enumerate(Matrix_List)] " to me? I understand the pad things, but the "word in enumerate(Matrix_List) " not

Comment: Its `i, word in enumerate(Matrix_List)` so you have the word in `word` and its index in `i`. For the left down direction you just need to pad the other way round.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may receive all the single character into a new list with using "for". Then by the index of new list, you may recall the letters and create the list however you want.